# CMake: how to properly setup new toolchain to avoid "System is unknown to CMake" message?

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I have setup a new CMake toolchain file to cross-compile for the STxP70 processor. I placed the file in my working directory and simply call cmake using:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=STxP70_toolchain.cmake ...
```

It works properly, but I always get a message that says:

```
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/STxP70 to use this system, please send your config file to cmake@www.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
```

Is there a way to place the toolchain file somewhere locally so that CMake will recognize it and not complain that the system is unknown? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your toolchain file `STxP70_toolchain.cmake` is found correctly by CMake, because otherwise you would see message like:

```
Could not find toolchain file: STxP70_toolchain.cmake
```

The message you see comes from setting variable `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`, e.g. command

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME="BLAH"
```

produces message:

```
System is unknown to cmake, create:
Platform/BLAH to use this system, please send your config file to cmake@www.cmake.org so it can be added to cmake
```

[Documentation](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling#Setting_up_the_system_and_toolchain) states:

> CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME:
>
> this one is mandatory, it is the name of the target
>   system, i.e. the same as CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME would have if CMake would
>   run on the target system. Typical examples are "Linux" and "Windows".
>   This variable is used for constructing the file names of the platform
>   files like Linux.cmake or Windows-gcc.cmake. If your target is an
>   embedded system without OS set CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME to "Generic". If
>   CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME is preset, the CMake variable CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING
>   is automatically set to TRUE, so this can be used for testing in the
>   CMake files.

You can set `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` to `Generic` to disable warning saying that `STxP70.cmake` is not present in the CMake distibution directory `install\path\to\CMake\share\cmake-2.8\Modules\Platform\`

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` to `Generic` effectively removed the warning. Thank you!